# Rending stateful components from array - grandchild state and parent state not aligning

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate, react-leaflet, react-state-management

I'm writing a user-editable component, which maintains user changes within its state.  I want to be able to use the component in 2 ways: **1:** Hardcoded by the author one at a time, or **2:** generated from an array from the parent component's state.  I am having trouble synchronizing states in the second scenario.  I want the component to be removable, so it has a "remove me" button, which should communicate with the parent's state through use of a callback function prop.

### The scenario:

Let say I have a parent component that has an array in its state.  From this array, child components are rendered using a `.map` statement:

```js
// in ParentComponent.js:

state = {
  markers: [
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 1"},
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 2"},
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 3"},
    ... etc ...
  ]
}

// In the return:

this.state.markers.map( (marker, index) => (
  <Marker key={index}>
    <Popup sourceKey={index} 
      setContentCallback={this.saveContentToState} 
      removalCallback={this.removalCallback} >
      {marker.popupContent}
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
))
```

The component in question is the granchild, `<Popup/>`.  From within Popup.js, the user can make changes to the component's content, and those changes are saved within the Popup's state:

```js
// In Popup.js

   state = { 
     content: this.props.children,
     inputValue: this.props.children
   }

   onEditHandler = { 
     this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value}) 
   }

   saveEdits = () => {
      if (this.props.saveContentCallback){
         this.props.saveContentCallback(this.state.inputValue, this.props.sourceKey)
      }
      this.setState({
         content: this.state.inputValue,
      })
   }

   removeSource = () => {
      if(this.props.removalCallback){
         this.props.removalCallback(this.props.sourceKey)
      } else {
         // internal leaflet function to remove a popup from a map
         this.thePopup.leafletElement._source.remove()
      }
   }

// Within the return function:
   return ( 
     <>
       <ContentEditableDiv onChange={this.onEditHandler}>
         { this.state.content }
       </ContentEditableDiv>
       <div onClick={this.saveEdits}>Save</div>
       <div onClick={this.removeSource}>Remove me</div>
     </>
   )
```

You can see how the component will maintain changes within its own state from the `saveEdits` function, in either of the scenarios mentioned above.  But in order to communicate changes with the parent's state, it makes use of the props `removalCallback` and `saveContentCallback`.  So, back in `ParentComponent.js`,

```js
  removalCallback = index => {
    mapRef.current.leafletElement.closePopup()
    this.setState(prevState => {
       prevState.markers.splice(index, 1)
       return {
          markers: prevState.markers
       }
    })
  }

   saveContentToState = (content, index) => {
      this.setState( prevState => {
         const newMarkers = prevState.markers
         newMarkers[index].popupContent = content
         return {
            ...this.state.newMarkers
         }
      })
   }
```

### Expected Behavior

When the 'remove' button is clicked on a Popup, I expect the callback to be called.  When the callback is called, it should remove that popup from the ParentComponent's state array 'markers', and the ParentComponent should rerender with only the remaining markers, with their associated `popupContent`.  So for example, if I start with this array:

```js
state = {
  markers: [
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 1"},
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 2"},
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 3"},
  ]
}
```

And then click the `remove me` button on popup 2, I should end up with this array:

```js
state = {
  markers: [
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 1"},
    {coords: Array(2), popupContent: "Popup 3"},
  ]
}
```

With two markers with popups that say "Popup 1" and "Popup 3" on them.

### Actual Behavior - The Bug

So I am indeed getting the expect array within the ParentComponent state as I just wrote above.  However, the popup's internal states are not cooperating.  When I click on the `remove me` button on popup #2, I get 2 resulting popups, but their content is "Popup 1" and "Popup 2".  When I look into the internal state of each `<Popup />` component, the `content` for each is "Popup 1" and "Popup 2" respectively.  Its as if when the `i`th popup is deleted, its internal state is somehow transfered to the `i+1`th popup, which transfers through all the Popups in the array.

### [Working Demo of the Problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/removal-callback-question-6045l)

This is a react-leaflet project, but I feel this is a react state management question.  Open up the render of the codesandbox, and you will see 5 popups.  When you click 'remove me' on any popup (except the last one), you'll see all the popup's numbers shift.  In the react dev tools components tab, you'll see that the `<Map />` (i.e. `<ParentComponent>`) state array is being updated correctly.  But looking at each `<EditablePopup />` internal state, these do not correspond with the state from the parent (`<Map`>) component.  I know that having something like `state = { content: this.props.something }` can cause problems, but I'm not sure if thats the culprit in this scenario.

What is going wrong here?  Shouldn't *all* these `<Marker/>` and `<Popup/>` components rerender each time the `removalCallback` or `saveContentCallback` fires, as it updates the parent's state and should trigger a rerender of the parent?  **I tried** adding a `this.forceUpdate` into these callbacks within the parent component, but that did nothing.  Sorry for the long question, *thanks for reading*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because you are not passing an unique key for each child element in the list. Without a unique key, React couldn’t differentiate if the element was removed or just the content is changed.

So, when you remove the item React’s diff algorithm thinks only the content got changed, because the key is not changed

The easiest way to test is to change the key for the `popupContent` like.

```
<Marker key={marker.popupContent} position={marker.coords}>
  ...
</Marker>
```

But this is not the solution. Create a unique key for each element in order to prevent issues in the future.

More info about how React’s diff algorithm works

> [How Diff Algorithm is implemented in Reactjs?](https://www.cronj.com/blog/diff-algorithm-implemented-reactjs/)

**Make sure your keys are unique!**

Comment: Yes!  This was it.  I had read once or twice that using the `index` as the `key` in a `.map` statement was a bad idea, but I never understood exactly why.  This situation is exactly why.  Because the key isn't unique, wierd things start to happen.  I replaced `key={index}` with `key={uuidv4()}`, using the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package.  I'll reward the bounty as soon as SO lets me.  I had a feeling the solution was simple, thanks for taking the time to read my long question.

Comment: @SethLutske it is always a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

you'd need to change the `line136` of `editablePopup.js` to get the latest children.

`{Parser(this.props.children)}`

working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/removal-callback-question-z9q6i

I've also noticed you're mutating the old state not the new one.

```
       const newMarkers = prevState.markers // But here you're mutating the old state. you should mutate copy of the state.
       newMarkers[index].popupContent = content
       return {
          ...this.state.newMarkers  
       }
```

Same below splicing you're mutating the prevState.

```
    this.setState(prevState => {
       prevState.markers.splice(index, 1) // User array filter with index !== i. So you will get a copy with filtered array. 
       return {
          markers: prevState.markers
       }
    })
```

Comment: So this does indeed, work, but only for scenario 2 mentioned at the start of my question.  It works because every time something is saved, it communicates back to the parent state, and if it changes, then the `this.props.children` has changed, and it rerenders.  This does not, however, work in scenario 1, where the component is hardcoded in, and the content is not read from the parent state, but rather from its own state.  Check out [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/removal-callback-question-thispropschildren-solution-cb9b9).  Also, your solution bypasses my `parsedChildren` clause

Comment: I had thought of rendering the content conditionally, like if `removalCallBack` or `saveContentCallBack` exists, I can do your solution.  But Sergio's solution above is a bit more comprehensive.